# I'm having an issue with PHP and Append File

Tags: php

I'm trying to use file_put_contents to manage bans in a .txt

However, I'm having trouble adding text or a new line amidst the text I'm adding.

I'm using $_GET to grab the reason and information of the banned person, i.e "loser,127.0.0.1" (simple example) and then add them to the txt. Thing is I can't figure out how to add a new line. When I try adding text

```
<?php
  file_put_contents("banned.txt", $_GET["r"], + "for example here", FILE_APPEND);
```

The code fails to run, *I'm not sure whether or not to actually have a comma either.* 
This is the code I'm trying to use as of now, and it does add a line, but it doesn't go to the next line.

```
<?php
  file_put_contents("banned.txt", $_GET["r"], FILE_APPEND);
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that it adds a new line, so if I said "loser,127.0.0.1" it adds that text to the txt, and goes to the next line for the next ban.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

get your ban data and explicitly add the new line:

```
$banData = $_GET["r"] . PHP_EOL;
```

If you want to write csv data in the file (in a very simple way) you can do so like this:

```
$banData = $_GET["ban_data"] . ";" . $_GET["ban_reason"] . PHP_EOL;
```

then simply write to the file

```
file_put_contents("banned.txt", $banData, FILE_APPEND);
```

instead of "banned.txt" save to "banned.csv" and you're set

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now. How do I close a thread lmao

Comment: How would I add multiple arguments? Such as:   file_put_contents("banned.txt", $banData, $banReason, FILE_APPEND);

Comment: In this case you would need to construct your file as a csv and set up two columns, banData and banReason. The line you would write would be comma or semicolon separated. I will edit my answer shortly to show this.

Comment: you don't close the thread :) it will stay on forever for other to find the question and answer later if they need similar information.

Answer (score 0):

First code is invalid as you should not have `,` between your GET reference and concatenated string. Once that is fixed, just add `\n` (`\r\n` on Windows) at the end of your string that you append and you should have new lines (or to stay platform agnostic, use `PHP_EOL` instead).